# Recorrer Lista y almacenar datos

Tags: json, flutter, https

Hola estoy haciendo un api{rest el cual trae datos de internet, utilizo http y seguido las indicaciones que están en el siguiente link https://esflutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

De la misma manera he seguido este link https://carlosamillan.medium.com/parseando-json-complejo-en-flutter-18d46c0eb045

pero no logro armar la clase y despues acceder al registro para guardar el campo por ejemplo cédula en una variable, necesito una ayuda para sacar el dato de cédula

```
{
"errors": [],
"messaje": [
    {
        "ano": "2021",
        "cedula": "xxxxxxx",
        "codigo_unico": "02000092328261001",
        "dia": "16",
        "emitido": "2021-07-01",
        "estado": "Cortado",
        "idc": "5600000038",
        "mes": "7",
        "nfactura": "000057217",
        "nombre": "ADRIANA DOLORES GUAPI GUALACIO",
        "plan": "Plan Start Servicio de Internet FO",
        "total": 145.0,
        "valor": 145.0,
        "vencimiento": "2021-07-16"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder recorrer esa lista primero debes validar que la misma no llegue vacía, primero supongamos que consumes la api desde una url cualquiera:

api: "https://miapi.com"

una vez tu consumas esta api te retorna lo que tu publicaste en la pregunta

```
   {
"errors": [],
"messaje": [
    {
        "ano": "2021",
        "cedula": "xxxxxxx",
        "codigo_unico": "02000092328261001",
        "dia": "16",
        "emitido": "2021-07-01",
        "estado": "Cortado",
        "idc": "5600000038",
        "mes": "7",
        "nfactura": "000057217",
        "nombre": "ADRIANA DOLORES GUAPI GUALACIO",
        "plan": "Plan Start Servicio de Internet FO",
        "total": 145.0,
        "valor": 145.0,
        "vencimiento": "2021-07-16"
    }
  ]
}
```

Primero creamos la clase para poder almacenar los objetos que nos trae el json, clase es la siguiente:

```
 class Messaje {
  String? cedula;
  String? nombre;

  Messaje({
    this.cedula,
    this.nombre,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "cedula": cedula,
      "nombre": nombre,
    };
  }

  factory Messaje.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Messaje(
      cedula: json["cedula"],
      nombre: json["nombre"],
    );
  }
}
```

No puse todos los campos para hacer el ejercicio más rapido.

Luego, en el método donde obtenemos los campos, iremos asignando los objetos a la lista, siempre y cuando no estén vacíos.

```
Future<List<Messaje>> metodoCosumoApi() async {
  List<Messaje> listMessaje = []
   
  //...
  //...
   final peticion = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://miapi.com")); 
   if(peticion.statusCode == 200){
   final list = jsonDecode(peticion["messaje"])
    if(list != null && list.isNotEmpty){
       for(var item in list){
         listMessaje.add(Messaje.fromJson(item))
        }
      }
   }
   //con este return ya tendríamos la lista de mensajes almacenados y ya vas a poder acceder a la data
   return listMessaje;
}
```

Comment: gracias hermano por la ayuda, pero disculpa como lo llamo al Future por ejemplo en el Scaffold, soy nuevo en esto, gracias

Comment: Podrías usar un FutureBuilder, te dejo aquí un link con un pequeño video https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pude resolver este problema

Comment: Si solucionaste el problema te pido que aceptes la respuesta, para que así personas con el mismo problema puedan encontrar una solución